# Flip effect condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

So I’m trying to figure out how to make a click effect work on mobile. I want the hover effect on desktop/laptop and the click effect on mobile.

Currently the hover effect is implemented. As you can see on my website's homepage: http://otownsend.ca/

What I need to figure out is how to implement the click effect at a certain screen size (e.g. 800px). So instead of the card flipping as soon as the curser hovers over ".flipper", the click effect would require the user to click ".flipper" in order for the card to flip. This would require me to place in a conditional statement - however, it isn’t working. I’m not so familiar with JQuery so it has been quite the challenge. This is what I currently have:

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)').matches)
{
    $('.flipper').click(function (e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
}
```

".flipper" is the parent element to the front and back. All the css and html is the same. I just need to integrate this JQuery stuff and then I’m set.

Any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `removeClass()` and `addClass()`. I've also changed your `click` event with `.on('click')`. I recommend you to use it that way. Also, add the code in `$(document).ready()`. I hope this is what you need. If not, please let me know and I will try a different approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flipper').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.flipped').removeClass('flipped');
    $(this).addClass('flipped');
  });
});
```

Regarding `matchMedia` you can see by running the test snippet that it works:

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 800px)').matches) {
  $('.flipper').css('color', '#f00');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='flipper'>
  testing matchMedia
</p>
```

Also, I've seen that in your code, you are doing something wrong. You are adding a `<script>` tag which contains `jQuery` source, inside another `<script>` tag(or you forgot to close the `</script>` tag). This is wrong. Please correct this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $(".flipper").flip({
        trigger: "hover"
      });
    });
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

To this:

```html
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 801px)').matches) {
       $(".flipper").flip({
         trigger: "hover"
       });
    }
 });
</script>
```

Notice the media query added for desktop only, from 801px up.

As a suggestion, I would like to recommend you to use a library like `Modernizr` for the media query part. Using Modernizr's way of using media queries, you won't have to refresh the page to see the changes like when using `matchMedia`. This also helps when you switch from portrait to landscape on mobile devices. You can read the docs about Modernizr media queries **[here](https://modernizr.com/docs)**.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! Can you please explain the purpose of removeClass and addClass for this case?

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend. Yes. I've used `removeClass` and `addClass` so on mobile, when you click an element, to add the class flipped and remove the class to the previous element with class `flipped`. I used this to be able to replicate the hover effect from desktop.

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend, what doesn't work mean?  Do you have any errors in your console? Please describe your problem so I can be able to help you.

Comment: To get a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve, you can look at the 1. "Transition On Hover" and the 2. "Transition On Click" effects. I'm trying to find a way to have an element that has 1. on desktop and laptop screen sizes and then have 2. for mobile screen sizes.

Comment: I understand that the JS is different in this case. But I'm willing to switch if this works over the previous suggestion.

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend, try adding the code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code goes here })`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend, Also I've found some other mistakes in your code. Read carefully my updated answer.

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same outcome without using javascript? For example, there's this program http://jsfiddle.net/unj3s/ which doesn't use javascript, but still achieves desktop and mobile usability for the same effect. I don't know what this user is doing differently in order to make theirs work. Any ideas?

Comment: @OliviaVictoriaTownsend, yeah, it's using hover effect instead of toggling class. But there is only one div, you have two, `front` and `back`.